# Finding the largest prime from a sum that equals $40$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> The sum of three different prime numbers is 40. What is the largest of the three primes?

I managed to get the solution for this as follows.

We have that $p_1+p_2+p_3 = 40$. Since $40$ is even we can deduce that one of the primes needs to be even, hence $p_1 = 2.$

So now the problem becomes to find $p_2, p_3$ such that $p_2 + p_3 = 40-2 = 38$.

From here on I tried multiple different ways, prime factoring $38$ didn't get me anywhere nor did prime factoring $40$. The only way I managed to find the answer was to list all the primes up to $38$, $\{2, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37 \}$. And from here we find that $p_2 = 31 $ and $p_3=7$. So $31$ was what we were looking for. If I wouldn't remember all the primes up to  $37$ I wouldn't have been able to do this, is there some other way which I could have done the problem which doesn't require me to memeber all the primes up to $37$?

Comment: i would think that any method would depend on knowing the primes $<37$.

Comment: Yes, just "solve" strong Goldbach for $n=38$ step by step. Start with $38=37+1$ impossible, then $38=36+2$ impossible etc. until $38=31+7$, yes, possible.

Comment: Once you found the even prime $2$, you can use an online linear Diophantine equation solver. https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/linear.html